# Tweepy returns only 76 tweets

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy

I am trying to gather movie reviews from Twitter. However, I get only 76 tweets. I tried to except tweeterror but that doesn't help. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import time
import cPickle as pickle
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(**hidden**)

auth.set_access_token(**hidden**)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
            "I am awake..."
        except tweepy.error:
            print "going to sleep..."
            time.sleep(15 * 60)
        except StopIteration:
            break

query = '#moviereview -filter:links'
max_tweets = 1000000

searched_tweets = [status.text for status in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets))]
with open("twitter_reviews.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(searched_tweets,f,-1)

print len(searched_tweets)
```

Comment: how many tweets were you expecting? can you add the error message please?

Comment: There is no error. I only get 76 tweets

Comment: and how many are you expecting?

Comment: Tweepy only returns Tweets from the past week (or maybe two). Could this be the problem? Although it looks like @glls has solved it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying your query parameters, as per your code, this is not what is filtering out further results.

Query for:

```
'#moviereview -filter:links'
```

provides 78 results (and counting)

Query for:

```
'#moviereview'
```

provides 1713 results (and counting)

Query for:

```
'#moviereview Filter:links'
```

provides 4534 results (and counting)

and as @Ethan mentioned + Twitters API documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets
>   published in the past 7 days.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Solved my problem